# Pass combobox selection to other combo box in another win form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have 2 windows forms, they both have same comboboxes with same possible selections. I want to pass selection from one combobox to another on button click.
I am passing values successfully to textboxes but when it comes to combobox, I cant figure it out.

Here is the code example:

Form 2 definition

```
private double passTxt;

private string passCB;

public double passTxtValue
        {
            get { return passTxt; }
            set { passTxt = value; }
        }
public string passCbValue
        {
            get { return passCB; }
            set { passCB = value; }
        }
```

Form 1 send

```
 private void btnPassValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2(); 

            form2.passTxtValue = variable1Form1;

            form2.passCbValue = CBForm1.SelectedText;
            form2.Show();
        }
```

Form2 - load (open)

```
private void form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            variable1Form2.Text = passTxt.ToString(); 
            CBForm2.SelectedText = passCB;
        }
```

When I check with debugger, the error is in step 2. Form1 send empty string ("") for `form2.passCbValue = CBValueForm1.SelectedText;`

When I try to use index or value it require cast but then there is an error that it can't be casted. Can someone tell me what i do wrong?

Comment: SelectedText is not what you think.

Comment: SelectedText is not text of selected item?
CBValueForm1 is ComboBox in form 1... i will edit it and remove this "Value" from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SelectedText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx) represent the current selected text in the TextBox area of a ComboBox with DropDown style (the blue highlighted text). This selection is cleared every time the combobox looses its focus (and when you are in the button click event, the focus is on the button).

The workaround is to pass the SelectedIndex of the combo on form1 (if the two combos are filled with the same items in the same order)

```
private void btnPassValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2(); 
    form2.passTxtValue = variable1Form1;
    form2.passCbIndex = CBValueForm1.SelectedIndex;
    form2.Show();
}
```

In form2 change the property to get an integer instead of a string....

```
private int passCBIndex;
public int passCbIndex
{
    get { return passCBIndex; }
    set { passCBIndex = value; }
}
```

and in your form2 Load event

```
private void form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ....
    CBValueForm2.SelectedIndex = passCBIndex;
}
```

Comment: This will probably suit you just fine, but I personally wouldn't use selectedindex because it relies on the items being the same and in the same sort order. Depending on how you populate those comboboxes there is a slight chance the order of items could be different.

Comment: the order in my project is same and the objects are same in all comboboxes.. i am fully aware that this can't help me if there is any difference

Answer (score 0):

Change it into:

```
form2.passCbValue = CBValueForm1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declare a Global string variable in the Form1
public String testValue;

//Assign the value had in the origin comboBox
testValue = cboOriginValue.Text;

//Create an Form2 Object Type and assign the value in the variable testValue
//to either the textbox or combobox components
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
//Make it visible 
form2.Visible = true;
form2.cboVehiculo.Text = tipoAutomovil;
form2.txtRecibe.Text = tipoAutomovil;
```

When you hit a button or whatever these lines of code being executed you'll have the  textboxes or comboboxes components populated with the selected value.

Hope it helps