# How to transfer data of selected value in comboBox from one form to another

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox

I have winform that shows the info of a company with a comboBox that shows the delegates of that company now If I select one of those delegates and clicked edit button for the selected delegate another form should appear with the info of that selected delegate to allow me modify the info; the common key between company and delegate tables is id so how to do this ???

this is my codes for the form of edit company

```
     delIdVar = Convert.ToInt32(compDelcombox.SelectedValue);              
     DelEditFrm delEditFrm = new DelEditFrm(delIdVar);
     delEditFrm.Show();
```

and this is the codes for the constructor of delegate edit form

```
public DelEditFrm(int delIdVar)
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     int delId = delIdVar; 
  }
```

and finally these codes for loading the columns data into textBoxes in my delegate edit form load event

```
     private void DelEditFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select delName,delAdd,delPhone1,delPhone2 from delegate where delId= ' delId  '", cn);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                delEditNametxt.Text = dr["delName"].ToString();
                delEditAddtxt.Text = dr["delAdd"].ToString();
                delEditPhone1txt.Text = dr["delPhone1"].ToString();
                delEditPhone2txt.Text = dr["delPhone2"].ToString();
            }
            catch(SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                dr.Close();
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
```

when I attempt to edit the selected delegate it gives me an exception "Convertion failed when converting the varchar value 'delId' to data type int " but the dilId column in my table is of int type

Comment: At a glance, [one of the related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275865/pass-combobox-selection-to-other-combo-box-in-another-win-form-c-sharp?rq=1) that shows down there under the job ads should work but there are many ways. Keep in mind forms are just classes, how would you provide a value from one object to another? With forms it is the same.

Comment: Please provide your code so we can help you

Comment: @Juran this is my codes for the form of edit company
    delIdVar = Convert.ToInt32(compDelcombox.SelectedValue);              
    DelEditFrm delEditFrm = new DelEditFrm(delIdVar);
    delEditFrm.Show();

Comment: @Juran and this is the codes for the constructor of delegate edit form
     public DelEditFrm(int delIdVar)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int delId = delIdVar; 
        }

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to:

1. Map the delegate to the id. (this can be stored or queried, if it's really a db)
2. When a delegate is selected, trigger a lookup of that id and populate the fields of a dialog box. (again, lookup or query)
3. Record changes when that dialog is closed. (a Modify on that item)

Comment: You should probably include some sample code and what you've attempted to get more high quality/informative answers. (Is this actually a SQL question? What are the queries involved? What have you tried?)